How does an intersection survive through (generic) perturbation?
I am looking for the proof of a folklore statement which I know (or heavily suspect) to be true, but haven't been able to find written down yet.
I have a (symplectic) manifold $M$ of dimension $2n$, and two (Lagrangian) submanifolds $L_1$, $L_2$ of dimension $n$ each. (I'm not sure the fact that they're symplectic/Lagrangian actually matters; and I believe everything will come down to dimensional reasons, which is why I put things in brackets).
Question: Let $x \in L_1\cap L_2$. I want to show that, for any open set $U$ containing $x$, there exists arbitrarily small perturbations $\phi(L_1)$ of $L_1$ such that $\phi(L_1)$ and $L_2$ also have an intersection point in $U$.
Note: when I say a perturbation $\phi(L_1)$ I usually mean a "Hamiltonian perturbation", ie $\phi$ is a Hamiltonian diffeomorphism. I guess this can also be relaxed to simply asking that $\phi$ be a diffeomorphism.
And when I say "arbitrarily small perturbation", I mean "close enough to the identity", in, say, the $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ sense. (Of course, this is true if my perturbation is the identity. I am looking for a non-trivial statement).
Other remark: I do know that transversality of intersections is a generic property, which sounds like it might be a good start. (A generic perturbation of $L_1$ will cause the two Lagrangians to intersect transversally in $U$ – if they do intersect). However, I'd like to know that this intersection is non-empty (for at least one perturbation).

Ideas: well, this is obvious in dimension $2n = 2$, at least. Indeed, we view our manifold $M$, as, locally, $\mathbb{R}^2 \cong T^{*}L_1 \cong T^{*}\mathbb{R}$; in which we view $L_1$ as the zero section, and $L_2$ as a graph over $L_1$ ($L_2$ is locally the graph of a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$). Then, an intersection point of $L_1$ and $L_2$ corresponds to a point $t$ where $f(t) = 0$. And it is an easy exercise in analysis to show that given any neighbourhood $U$ of $t$, one can slightly perturb $f$ so that it still has a $0$ in $U$ (this is basically a corollary of the intermediate value theorem).
For higher dimensions though, I don't know how to generalize the reasoning above; for it really works because of $1$-dimensional arguments. Though I'm fairly sure that the question I asked is true.
Hence, if anyone has an idea, or a reference which contains the proof of such a statement, I would be very interested. :)

You need to know the intersection is transverse in the first place, or else your claim is false. Consider the $t$-axis and the graph of $f(t)=t^2$. Perhaps I missed a technicality in what you wrote.

I also don't think that the question makes sense in the form your asking it ("there exists a small perturbation ..."). In this form you can just take $\phi=id$. The question should be whether for any sufficiently small perturbation there still is an intersection.

@TedShifrin this is not a problem. I didn't say "every close enough perturbations has an intersection". I said "there exists arbitrarily small perturbations with intersection". This is absolutely true for $f(t) = t^2$.

@AndreasCap alright, then my question is "choose a perturbation that is not the identity".

This formally makes sense, but you can still have deformations that leave the intersection point fixed.

As expressed in the comments to the question, without further requirements on the perturbation, the question admits relatively simple solutions.

The identity (Hamiltonian) diffeomorphism $\phi : M \to M$ works.

Suppose we want to exclude the identity diffeomorphism. Then there are arbitrarily small Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms $\phi : M \to M$ ('small' under essentially any norm you would like e.g. $C^0$, $C^{\infty}$, Hofer, ...) fixing $x$.


Proof: Take the time-one map associated to a $C^{\infty}$-small Hamiltonian function having a critical point at $x$.

Suppose we want to exclude a Hamiltonian diffeomorphism that fixes $x$. Then consider another point $y \in L'_1 := \phi(L_1)$. Then there is a Hamiltonian diffeomorphism $\psi$ that fixes $L'_1$ (i.e. $\psi(L'_1) = L'_1$) such that $\psi(y) = x$, so taking $z := \phi^{-1}(y) \in L_1$, we see that $(\psi \circ \phi)(z) = x \in (\psi \circ \phi)(L_1) \cap L_2$.

Proof of existence of $\psi$: Since $L'_1$ is embedded, by Weinstein's neighborhood theorem, there is a neighborhood of $(L'_1, \omega)$ that is symplectomorphic to a tubular neighborhood of the zero section in $T^*L'_1$. Time-one maps of isotopies of diffeomorphisms of $L'_1$ lift to Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms on $T^*L'_1$ fixing the zero section. Since the group of such diffeotopies of $L'_1$ is transitive, we obtain a Hamiltonian diffeomorphism in (a neighborhood of the zero section of) $T^*L'_1$ sending $y$ to $x$. If $y$ is sufficiently close to $x$, then this diffeomorphism can be taken $C^0$ or even $C^{\infty}$ small. To obtain a well-defined on $M$, one can arrange that the Hamiltonian diffeomorphism be supported in a neighborhood of $L'_1$ (for instance by multiplying the Hamiltonian function by a bump function). (This procedure work in the $C^0$-small or Hofer-small sense, but one needs to be more careful to get to a $C^{\infty}$-small Hamiltonian diffeomorphism.)

Suppose we want to exclude Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms that fix $L'_1 = \phi(L_1)$. Then postcompose $\psi$ by an arbitrary (small) Hamiltonian diffeomorphism $\phi' : M \to M$ fixing $x$ but not $L'_1$. Then $\phi' \circ \psi \circ \phi$ sends $z \in L_1$ to $x$.

One sees that Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms are flexible enough to allow for a lot of things to happen.
